# xcode, argument set but being ignored when launched from device

Tags: xcode5

I have an argument setup on one of my apps. When the app is launched from Xcode, the argument is passed fine, i can see it being outputted to the console.

When the app is launched from the phone, not xcode, the argument is missing, it returns 0 on the following code

```
NSProcessInfo *proc = [NSProcessInfo processInfo];
NSArray *args = [proc arguments];
if([args count] > 1)
{
    NSString *myArg = [args objectAtIndex: 1];
    if([myArg isEqualToString:@"PROVERSION"])
        [appData setIsPro:TRUE];
}

NSLog(@"Is Pro: %hhd", [appData isPro]);
```

In the scheme, the argument is set in Product->Run like the apple library says

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for...there is no way to give arguments to a process from a phone.  You need to do something else, e.g. install a file in the bundle (such as a property list) and use `NSBundle` APIs to read its data at runtime.

Comment: I have one project that has two targets. One which is paid for, and one which is free.  Since they are both made using the same files I need a way to differentiate between they so that the paid for one doesn't load the ads

Comment: Xcode certainly allows you to install different files for different targets.  You shouldn't be forced to use exactly the same ones in each build.

Comment: I know. Originally I had it setup similarly to that but it became a nightmare trying to keep both sets of files up to date so I decided it would probably be easier to have one set

Comment: In one of my projects I made the source file a template of sorts (because 99% of it was unchanging), combined with a build script that could substitute one piece, e.g. by searching for some `%TOKEN%`.  That can be a good way to create 2 target files out of one source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using a preprocessor macro defined in the build settings instead